# Why does a project not get created using my .NET Core custom template in VS Community 2022?

Tags: asp.net-core, templates, visual-studio-2022, vs-community-edition

I have created a custom .NET Core template using the exact steps given in Sayed Hashimi's tutorials here:

1. [Create a .NET Core Project Template](https://youtu.be/GDNcxU0_OuE)
2. [Create a .NET Core Project Template for Visual Studio](https://youtu.be/2hpNFrY_faI)
3. [Sayed Hashimi's Template Sample Github project](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/template-sample)

(NOTE: I have created 4 C# projects in a single solution, and created the template.json for the Solution, and NOT for the C# projects.)

I am able to create a new .NET Core project using the "dotnet new <template_name> -o My.New.ProjectName", wherein it gets created correctly.

However, when I try to create the same using "Create a New Project" option in the VS 2022 startup screen, and then select my new template, and proceed with the

[image: The "Create a new project" option]

[image: The New Project Template]

[image: The entered options]

[image: The new project having nothing in it]

I tried uninstalling the template, re-packaging it using nuget.exe and reinstalling.
Alas, the result is still the same.

Oh great StackOverflow community, kindly help!

Comment: Unfortunately you are not the first person to post this exact issue before. I would say you are the 10th person or so! Close Visual Studio and make sure you open the .sln file and not a .csproj, but seeing that you just created the project, I'm unsure if that will work. The only solution I've seen someone say worked was uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio (sometimes multiple times)

Comment: I don't find definitive answer about this issue, You can post an issue in Asp.Net Core or Visual Studio Github library, Maybe the Microsoft developer can give you some help.